# Migrating Vmware to Hyper-V - number of Virtual CPU

Tags: performance, virtual-machines, vmware-vcenter, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I'm performing a migration from VmWare to Hyper-V and the Virtual CPU that you are assigning to a Virtual Machine is different and I'd like to know what should be the equivalent values when we move a VMachine from Vmware to Hyper-V

For example On VmWare we have a 2008 R2 standard that is configured with 4Cores and 2 Virtual Sockets, VmWare configuration reports "Total number of cores: 8"

When I will migrate the VmWare to Hyper-V, should I assign 8 Processors to Virtual Machine? That's will be the equivalent configuration to have similar performance tha I'll have on VmWare? (I don't have many other options to configure on Hyper-V).

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

As you described it, that would be the equivalent. 8 cores = 8 vCPU's on HyperV.

I would ask/state the follow up question/statements: 1) make sure your physical host has at least 8 cores. 2) does your guest really need 8 vCPU's?

Comment: I'll probably doesn't need 8 vCPU's, but we need to get equivalent performance that we have in VmWare. (because Physical hosts are the same) And people is complaining about HYPER-V Performance

Comment: There is a lot more to equivalent performance than just matching the number of CPU's.. digging into general performance is probably a bit too broad for serverfault. Can you provide specific metrics to narrow down where the performance might be a bottleneck and why you are focusing first on the number of vCPU's?

Answer (score 1):

First off you need to know your host configuration will it support 8V-CPUs? Most modern servers will easily meet or surpass this, but its worth a check.

The second thing to ask yourself does this server **NEED** 8V-CPUs?

Well giving it lots of VCPUs will make things faster right?

Well if it’s the only VM running on the system may be, but in most use cases we virtualise to consolidate running 10/20 VM’s on a single host. Sometimes a lot more depending on the situation.

So you will have a lot of VM’s asking for CPU time the more VCPU’s allocated out the more WAIT time Hyper-V will be asking for (essentially telling the VM to wait for CPU time)  this can be from Nano seconds to seconds. 
There is some good reading [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2011/02/14/hyper-v-cpu-scheduling-part-1.aspx)

```
    **TLDR;**


Yes you are correct 1 CORE = 1 VCPU
```